# Why do I get the error message "Error: grouping factors must have > 1 sampled level" when I do a glmer?

Tags: sampling, lme4-nlme

My model is:

```
model1 <- glmer(Avg_egg_mass ~ Treatment + Alt_cat + Treatment:Alt_cat + (1|Nest) + (1|Site)+ (1|Year), na.action=na.omit, family = poisson (link=log), data = dframe1)
```

where I am relating average egg mass (continous variable) to a four group treatment (set to factor) and three categories of altitude (also set to factor).

It doesn't seem to work and I get this error message 
`Error: grouping factors must have > 1 sampled level`.

Comment: If your response is continuous, a Poisson model is mis-specified.

Comment: @user777 You would be interested, then, in reading the post at http://blog.stata.com/tag/poisson-regression/ explaining how and why such a model can be useful.

Comment: @whuber That post is very interesting, and illustrates a use of Poisson regression I was not aware of. But I can't wrap my mind around something simple: if $P$ is a Poisson PMF, then $P(2.5)=0$. So am I correct that the procedure uses an analogue to the Poisson distribution with support over $\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: @user777 Good point. The fitting is done using maximum likelihood. The contribution to the "likelihood" of the parameter $\lambda$ due to any nonnegative integral value $x$ can be rewritten $\exp(-\lambda)\lambda^x/x!=\exp(x\log(\lambda)-\lambda)/\Gamma(x+1),$ which actually is defined for all real (indeed, complex) values of $x$. I believe that is what is used in this generalized application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's happening is that your data are cast as factors, but not all levels of that factor appear in your data. So you can't group your data by these non-present factors. You'll either have to use a superset of this data which includes all levels of the factors, or re-level the grouping columns to have levels only for the groups present in the column.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! That makes sense and I have changes my categories for altitude. Instead I now get the warning messages "1: In (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L,  ... :non-integer x = 4.500000". Could you by any chance explain why this is happening now? Cheers

Comment: @Aisha I can't say for sure. My advice would be to look at your data and find where the value 4.5 occurs. Wherever it is, the fit procedure doesn't like non-integer values to be there.

Comment: The non-integer values issue was actually related to a different model, where I looked at rate of female provisioning per hour in relation to the above variables. I can't really change these values to integers.

Comment: @Aisha It sounds like you still have some questions. That's fine! If it's a statistics-related question, ask it here. If it's more related to programming, Stack Overflow is the correct place to ask.

Comment: Yes, I'm still  a little confused. So I get the same integer warning messages in a few of my models. For example when I run this glmer: model1 <- glmer(Avg_egg_mass ~ Treatment + Alt + Treatment:Alt + (1|Obs), family = poisson(link=log), data = dframe1) and the output is: "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages: 1: In (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L,  ... :non-integer x = 1.010000"

Comment: @Aisha Sorry, I should have been more clear. I meant that you should ask a new question here if it is statistics related, and ask a new question on stack overflow if it's more to do with programming.